# Determine the range numeric scope from column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function, sumifs

I am using following `SUMIF` formula in sheet2:

```
=SUMIF(sheet1'!B1:B200,D7,'sheet1'!F1:F200)
```

There is a month in column A such as Jan from `A1` to `A200` and Feb from `A201` to `A300`. I want to input Jan (Feb or any other) in some cell of sheet2 and then get its range, it is 1 to 200 in this case. Finally, this range will be used in `SUMIF` formula to get the result.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  SUMPRODUCT might do everything you need without the extra column holding the range that matches the month.

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMIFS('sheet1'!F1:F200,sheet1'!B1:B200,D7,'sheet1'!A1:A200,"Jan")` should work for Jan, or replace the hard coding for the month with a cell reference (E7?)

SUMIFS uses a different sequence from SUMIF (see [for example](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/90107sumifs.htm)).